# Chart Click event does not handle two Datapoints with same coordinate x and y

Tags: vb.net, scatter-plot, mschart

I have a problem with showing two labels at same point of coordinate. The problem arises when two different objects in an array have same x and y values.
The whole application is about a plant layout which shows activities at different places of plant and put a "Marker" using objects coordiantes.
You can consider this by taking example of a family in which all persons have different charteristics like age, height, weight, facecolor but they still live in same place or location their home.

The VB code describes this problem as:

```
For Index_i = 0 To myTotalFiles - 1
  For Index_j = 0 To TotalLine - 1
    If (Worker(Index_i).Location = MapLocations(Index_j).NameOfLocation) Then
       Worker(Index_i).X = MapLocations(Index_j).XCoord
       Worker(Index_i).Y = MapLocations(Index_j).YCoord
       series.Points.AddXY(Worker(Index_i).X, Worker(Index_i).Y)                    
    End If
    Next
 Next
```

MapLocations() is an array of objects that holds three properties NameOfLocation, XCoord and YCoord.

The Line Worker(Index_i).Location = MapLocations(Index_j).NameOfLocation Compares worker location (String) to that of MapLocation MapLocations(Index_j).NameOfLocation(String)
if it matches then gives the worker a coordinate pair as

```
Worker(Index_i).X = MapLocations(Index_j).XCoord
Worker(Index_i).Y = MapLocations(Index_j).YCoord
```

and Add a Marker on the plot.

The chart also implements to show a message or tooltip when clicked on marker. If two workers have same x and y values then Markers will be exactly overlapping
and will not give information for both of them, How can this be avoided.

The chart click event is given as:

```
Private Sub Chart1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Chart1.Click
        Try
            Dim pointindex As Integer
            Dim result As HitTestResult
            result = Chart1.HitTest(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y)
            If result.ChartElementType = ChartElementType.DataPoint Then
                pointindex = result.PointIndex
                MsgBox("Worker is working at: " + Worker(pointindex).Location + vbLf+ "With Scope of work: " + Worker(pointindex).Scope)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

[All Coordiantes for Map Location are saved in a file and read and then matche with a Worker's Location and then Place a Marker at this point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nvM3.png)

Comment: What ChartType do you use? Can you show the actual chart?

Comment: Since this type of plotting a location needs scatter plot I used: 
        Dim series As New Series
        series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point
An Image is also attached with this question for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `C#` routine that extracts all points with the same x- and y-values as the one you clicked, i.e. the top/last one:

```
    private void chart_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var hitt = chart.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        Text = hitt.PointIndex + "";

        if (hitt.PointIndex >= 0)
        {
           DataPoint dp = chart.Series[0].Points[hitt.PointIndex];
           var points = chart.Series[0].Points.
                    Where(x => x.XValue == dp.XValue && 
                               x.YValues[0] == dp.YValues[0]);
           ..  // now you can enumerate all the points to create a message..
           foreach (DataPoint p in points)..
        }
}
```

A `VB` version ought to be rather similar.